# Can I use "for" from label as a href?

Tags: jquery, html, css, label

I have at least 10 elements like this. This snippet is one dropdown with content in it. Every dropdown like this have a unique ID and FOR and I want every dropdown to lead to next and the previous one through the buttons at the end

The question is how to create the buttons to lead to next or previous dropdown when having labels. Can I point to the "for" with href?

I try the `<a href="#id">` but this does not work.

[Here is the CodePen for example.](https://codepen.io/petyoyo/pen/OQRVvZ) 
This is made for mobile and that is why is so big.

Can you suggest me a solution?

```
<div id="container">
  <section id="accordion">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="pin" />
      <label for="pin">DROPDOWN TITLE</label>
      <article>
        <div class="row row2">
          <h3>HEADLINE</h3>

          <div class="row vert-center">

          <div class="col-xs-6">
          <img src="images/demo-image" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p>TEXT HERE</p>
          </div></div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 prev-step">
              <a class="buttons" href="#first-step"><p>NEXT STEP</p></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 next-step">
              <a class="buttons" href="#pin"><p>NEXT STEP</p></a>
            </div></div>

      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Click on the button to jump up to the label?  It is not very clear what your next step button should do

Comment: I have at least 10 elements like. This snippet is one dropdown with content in it. Every dropdown like this have a unique ID and FOR and I want every dropdown to lead to next and the previous one through the buttons at the end.

Comment: If JavaScript is an option you can just scroll to the label with the desired for. You can't jump to that label using a fragment because then you wouldn't be able to jump to the input with the same id that the label is associated with (and the standard isn't going to bend over just to accommodate your use case).

Comment: Change them to labels and use a for tag then instead of anchors as it looks like you are just trying to target the checkboxes to do things (by the looks though, you are trying to do a css accordion and your checkbox should most likely be next to the article, but as you have not created a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem, I cannot really comment on that part

Comment: Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/petyoyo/pen/OQRVvZ
Also added in the description.

Comment: There are two reasons why your code is not working. 1. You are targeting a hidden element (input) with href. 2. Use unique id´s